# Postgre локальная установка (local setup)

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, unix

Привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу понять, и как следствие, решить. Устанавливал на ubuntu Rails и всё к нему прилагающееся. И требовалось мне установить postgreSQL, и сделать это локально. И на этом моменте всё плохо. Следуя инструкциям, добавил:

```
$ export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)
```

whoami - в моём случае lord. После этого мне нужно:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
== 20140707111715 CreateWidgets: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:widgets)
   -> 0.0076s
== 20140707111715 CreateWidgets: migrated (0.0077s) ===========================
```

Фактический:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "ruby-getting-started_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/home/lord/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
....
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"ruby-getting-started_development"}
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
: CREATE DATABASE "ruby-getting-started_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
/home/lord/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-...
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"ruby-getting-started_test"}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "ruby-getting-started_development" does not exist
....
/home/lord/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

В интернете залез в дебри, но так и не смог решить эту проблему.

Comment: Стоит дополнить, что пользовался инструкциями: 
[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction), и застрял на пункте обявления зависимостей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> permission denied to create database

Собственно, у пользователя от имени которого вы подключаетесь к СУБД нет прав на создание новых баз данных, что является нормальным для непривилегированных пользователей.

Вам необходимо авторизоваться в PostgreSQL от имени суперпользователя БД (обычно это пользователь `postgres`, и внимание, это не про суперпользователя ОС `root`), типично вот так:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

И далее на выбор:

- создать БД и предоставить все права на её использование определённому пользователю

  ```
  create database dbname owner lord;
  ```

  что правильно, у пользователя приложения не должно быть лишних прав. Создание баз данных - явно лишние права для приложения.
- предоставить права на создание базы данных пользователю

  ```
  alter user lord CREATEDB ;
  ```
- разобраться с системой прав PostgreSQL и как её можно использовать в RoR для полноценного разграничения прав доступа - одному пользователю из приложения допускать только `select/insert/update/delete` операции (и отдельно пользователь для `read-only` который может делать только `select`), `create table` и другие `DDL` операции разрешать только пользователю, который применяет миграции. Т.е. минимум прав для работы, что хорошо с точки зрения безопасности и в коммерческих проектах.

Вы сейчас очевидно только изучаете платформу, так что разбираться с деталями разграничения прав доступа будет пока избыточно. Оптимально создать базу данных вручную и предоставить её целиком пользователю

```
create database dbname owner lord;
```

Что, к слову, тоже очень часто используется в действующих проектах.

Шаг `db:create` при этом вероятно надо будет убрать из команды, но не могу сказать точно, с рельсами не сталкивался.